# Docker, Supervisord and logging - how to consolidate logs in docker logs?

Tags: python, django, logging, supervisord, docker

So, experimenting with Docker + Supervisord + Django app via uWSGI. I have the whole stack working fine, but need to tidy up the logging.

If I launch supervisor in non-daemon mode,

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -n
```

Then I get the logging output for supervisor played into the docker logs stdout. However, if supervisord is in daemon mode, its own logs get stashed away in the container filesystem, and the logs of its applications do too - in their own app__stderr/stdout files.

What I want is to log both supervisor, and application stdout to the docker log.

Is starting supervisord in non-daemon mode a sensible idea for this, or does it cause unintended consequences? Also, how do I get the application logs also played into the docker logs?

Comment: I have seen running supervisord in non-daemon mode in [hipache Dockerfile](https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache/blob/master/Dockerfile). I guess that's one good way of doing it. Can you please educate me on 'docker logs'? :)

Comment: @chanux he's referring to the output of `docker logs $CONTAINER_ID`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree, not using the daemon mode sounds like the best solution, but I would probably employ the same strategy you would use when you had actual physical servers or some kind of VM setup: centralize logging.

You could use something self-hosted like [logstash](http://logstash.net/) inside the container to collect logs and send it to a central server. Or use a commercial service like loggly or papertrail to do the same.

Answer (score 42):

I accomplished this using .

Install [supervisor-stdout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor-stdout) in your Docker image:

```
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip && pip install supervisor-stdout
```

#### Supervisord Configuration

Edit your `supervisord.conf` look like so:

```
[program:myprogram]
command=/what/ever/command
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true

[eventlistener:stdout] 
command = supervisor_stdout 
buffer_size = 100 
events = PROCESS_LOG 
result_handler = supervisor_stdout:event_handler
```

Comment: Of course the accepted answer is the way to go, but this answer gives the easiest way to get it working quickly. ;)

Comment: standard `python-pip` install on our ubuntu 16.04 takes 194MiB, so we used the following: `apt-get install --no-install-recommends python-pip python-setuptools python-wheel` (2.6MiB)

Comment: This doesn't work any more for python 3. Reason is that the supervisor-stdout package was not updated in the pypi repository. You need to install git using 'apt-get install -y git' and install supervisor_stdout using 'pip install git+https://github.com/coderanger/supervisor-stdout.git'

Answer (score 28):

Docker container is like a kleenex, you use it then you drop it. To be "alive", Docker needs something running in foreground (whereas daemons run in background), that's why you are using Supervisord.

So you need to "redirect/add/merge" process output (access and error) to Supervisord output you see when running your container.

As Drew said, everyone is using https://github.com/coderanger/supervisor-stdout to achieve it (to me this should be added to supervisord project!). Something Drew forgot to say, you may need to add

```
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

To the supervisord program configuration block.

Something very usefull also, imagine your process is logging in a log file instead of stdout, you can ask supervisord to watch it:

```
[program:php-fpm-log]
command=tail -f /var/log/php5-fpm.log
stdout_events_enabled=true
stderr_events_enabled=true
```

This will redirect php5-fpm.log content to stdout then to supervisord stdout via supervisord-stdout.

Comment: I've tried adding stdout_logfile and stdout_logfile_maxbytes to my supervisord configuration but it didn't work. But this configuration (https://gist.github.com/alterEgo123/4f7622081729663b689e957f7a31dac9) did. My question is, is this a bad implementation of your solution?

Answer (score 23):

supervisor-stdout requires to install python-pip, which downloads ~150mb, for a container I think is a lot just for install another tool.

Redirecting logfile to /dev/stdout works for me:

```
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/08/supervisord-redirecting-stdout.html

Comment: This was the cleanest way I found also, doesn't require any extra packages.

Answer (score 1):

Today's best practice is to have minimal Docker images. For me, ideal container with Python application contain just my code, supporting libraries and something like `uwsgi` if it is necessary.

I published one solution on https://github.com/msgre/uwsgi_logging. It is simple Django application behind `uwsgi` which is configured to display logs from `uwsgi` and Django app on containers stdout without need of `supervisor`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my python app (Flask). Solution that worked for me was to:

- Start **supervisord** in nodaemon mode (`supervisord -n`)
- Redirect log to `/proc/1/fd/1` instead of `/dev/stdout`
- Set these two environment variables in my docker image  `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True` and `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

Just add below line to your respective supervisor.ini config file.

```
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/proc/1/fd/1
```

Export these variables to application (linux) environment.

```
$ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True 
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, starting supervisord in non-daemon mode is the best solution.

You could also use volumes in order to mount the supervisord's logs to a central place.